# android.settings.INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS doesn't work with HTC hero

Tags: android, htc-hero

My application has a button that sends the user to the locale setting.
I do this with this code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS));
```

This works fine with some devices, but with the HTC Hero I get:

```
02-03 13:59:27.501: INFO/ActivityManager(69): Starting activity: Intent { action=android.settings.INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS flags=0x10000000 }
02-03 13:59:27.531: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1916): Shutting down VM
02-03 13:59:27.531: WARN/dalvikvm(1916): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40013140)
02-03 13:59:27.531: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-03 13:59:27.611: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { action=android.settings.INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS flags=0x10000000 }
02-03 13:59:27.611: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1529)
02-03 13:59:27.611: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1499)
02-03 13:59:27.611: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2669)
02-03 13:59:27.611: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1916):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2713)
```

EDIT:
SOLUTION!

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
ComponentName com = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.LanguageSettings");
intent.setComponent(com); startActivity(intent);
```

The previous code will work on every device :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially, you probably cannot fix it. HTC apparently broke the SDK with the particular Hero firmware you are running. You can use `android.os.Build` to identify that you are on a Hero and disable whatever option leads to the failing `startActivity()` call (e.g., disable the menu choice that tries to open up these settings).

Unofficially, try going to that screen manually via the Settings application, and take a look at the LogCat output. You might be able to determine that way an Intent that can trigger the specific screen you seek, if one exists.

Comment: great idea I fix it!
Plz add this to your answer and I will give it as correct:

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    ComponentName com = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.LanguageSettings");
    intent.setComponent(com);
    startActivity(intent);