# How to start Language and Input Intent through XML?

Tags: android, xml, android-intent

`<intent android:action="android.provider.Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS"/>`
does not work anymore. I found an answer
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192419/android-settings-input-method-settings-doesnt-work-with-htc-hero).

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
ComponentName com = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.LanguageSettings");
intent.setComponent(com); startActivity(intent);
```

But the problem is that I need to find the equivalent code to launch this intent through XML. Is this possible?

Comment: Note that your approach may not work on all devices, as there is no requirement for there to be an exported `com.android.settings.LanguageSettings` activity in an app named `com.android.settings`.

Comment: Is there any other way to launch that intent?

Comment: Well, there is no guaranteed way to do it in general. `ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS` works as well now as it ever has, as it is [still in the manifest as of Android 6.0](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml). You need to accept the fact that you cannot guarantee any way to get to that activity, and so doing it from what I assume is preference XML is not going to work well. From Java, you can see if the `Intent` resolves to anything and gracefully degrade if you cannot find a way to that activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind I found an answer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html). Since

```
android:targetClass
```

Is the class part of the component name, as per the setComponent() method.
and

```
android:targetPackage
```

The package part of the component name, as per the setComponent() method.

and also according to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html),

```
ComponentName(String package, String class)
```

So the equivalent XML code for this is:

```
<intent android:action="android.intent.action.MAIN"
android:targetPackage="com.android.settings"
android:targetClass="com.android.settings.LanguageSettings" />
```

Although just like Mr.[CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) said, It is not advisable to use this method (Read his comment to my original post). But for those who still want to use this method, go ahead. Hope this helps :)